# Tag Libraries for Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing a web application using Spring MVC. Although Spring MVC comes with a couple of tag libraries, they are not rich as Struts' counterpart. What I miss most is `<html:xhtml>`.

Those of you using Spring MVC, what third-party tag libraries do you guys use?

Thanks!

Edit: More specifically, I would like to auto-generate the following using a custom tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: You're specifically asking about HTML form tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is generate that fragment, then what's wrong with `<jsp:include>`, or a simple tagfile, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<jsp:doBody>
</html>
```

Stick that in `/WEB-INF/tags/xhtml.tag`, and you're done, e.g.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<tags:xhtml>
   // Rest of content in here
</tags:xhtml>
```

Comment: It would be kind of awkward to write something like <jsp:include path="html" /> and </html>. It would be more readable to write <html:html> and </html:html>.

Comment: +1 for promoting tag files, although the struts xhtml tag also sets a flag that makes all struts tags render in xml mode, ie using `/>` for empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the spring's form taglib

"<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>"

it is html 4.01 and XHTML1.0 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5's doctype being much more simple, all you need to have now for a doctype is `<!doctype html>` which is just as short, or shorter, than most tag libs, and also has much less overhead.

All you need now is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
</html>
```

The best solution, however, is still to put your basic boilerplate into an include file like @skaffman suggested. This lets you get the boilerplate nice and optimized and then you can keep using the same one and don't have to worry about it any more. The [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) project is a good place to start for that.